# markdown-package: problem with # sign in url and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, markdown

I use the markdown-package in combination with pdfLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[    
        blankBeforeBlockquote,
        blankBeforeCodeFence,
        codeSpans,
        citations,
        definitionLists,
        fencedCode,
        hybrid,
        underscores,
        inlineFootnotes,
        hashEnumerators ]{markdown}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{markdown}

Here's a link to [a website](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/fundamentals.html#testing-pyramid).  

\end{markdown}
\end{document}
```

If I compile the above code, I get following error message.

> Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa.

I presume this has something to do with macros, because macro arguments are led by #.

---

I also tried the following tip the complier gave me. This works for compilation, but than the link is broken in the pdf `...html#%23testin...`.

> You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
>   Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
>   are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.

---

The markdown-package generates a tmp file, that looks like this, maybe it helps for answering:

```
Here's a link to \markdownRendererLink{a website}{https://developer.android.com/training/testing/fundamentals.html#testing-pyramid}{https://developer.android.com/training/testing/fundamentals.html#testing-pyramid}{}.\relax
```

---

I am not that deep into macros, so I am not shure, if there can something be done.

Comment: Untested: maybe `\#` instead of `#` works here.

Comment: @Marijn sorry, but `\#` doesn't work for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imho the only thing that works is to temporarly change the catcode of #:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
        blankBeforeBlockquote,
        blankBeforeCodeFence,
        codeSpans,
        citations,
        definitionLists,
        fencedCode,
        hybrid,
        underscores,
        inlineFootnotes,
        hashEnumerators ]{markdown}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\begin{markdown}

Here's a link to {\catcode`\#=12 [a website](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/fundamentals.html#testing-pyramid).}

\end{markdown}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I did need to change the \catcode command to `{\catcode35=12 [a website](url).}` but else it worked fine

Comment: The alternative linking methode in markdown works also like this: `{\catcode35=12 [Linktext][refToLink]}` and `[refToLink]: https://...`

Comment: Not sure why you "need" to use `\catcode35`, but it is the same -- `` `\# ``  is only a different way to write 35 which avoids that one has to remember the number.

Comment: It is a special character in markdown and therefor I got another problem. A mix of Markdown and LaTeX is maybe a bit overkill, but I like the simplicity of Markdown and the beautiful PDF Document I get from LaTeX.

Comment: There is an alternative package-specific solution that involves redefining the `\markdownRendererLink` TeX command and that does not require you to litter your markdown markup with macros. I will post the solution later, but you can see the technical documentation for yourself in the meantime \[[1](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/markdown/markdown.pdf#page=17)], \[[2](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/markdown/markdown.pdf#page=94)].

Comment: @Witiko I tried to redefine the \markdownRendererLink but couldn't find a working solution. It will be interesting to see which one you found. Be aware that the OP is using pdflatex, so the solution must work through the temporary file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer For ease of debugging, LuaTeX uses a temporary file as well although it could just `tex.sprint(…)` the result of the conversion. I am thinking of having `\markdownRendererLink` not consume any parameters. Instead, it would switch the catcode and then insert an actual command that would typeset the hyperlink and switch the catcode back.

Comment: @Witiko this could work but imho needs changes in the package code and can not be done through the official interface.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You are right that it can not be done through the LaTeX interface, but you can just redefine `\markdownRendererLink` directly – it is not an package internal, it is a part of the plain TeX interface and expected to be redefined by the user.

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in the comment section of Ulrike Fischer's answer, you can redefine `\markdownRendererLink` so that it changes the category code of the hash sign (`#`) before the parameters have been consumed. This keeps the logic separate from the markdown markup:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{markdown}
\def\markdownRendererLink{%
  \begingroup
  \catcode`\#=12
  \def\next##1##2##3##4{%
    \markdownRendererLinkPrototype{##1}{##2}{##3}{##4}\endgroup}%
  \next}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{markdown}
Here's a link to [a website]
(https://developer.android.com/training/testing/fundamentals.html#testing-pyramid).  
\end{markdown}
\end{document}
```

`\markdownRendererLinkPrototype` is the default command for rendering hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

May I note, that the same issue arises with the ifthenelse package:

```
\ifthenelse{\isnamedefined{ProcessIntegrationDevice}} {%
  \url{https://sourceforge.net/p/com0com/bugs/32/#c463}
```

The solution in normal latex seems to be:

```
\url{https://sourceforge.net/p/com0com/bugs/32/\#c463}
```

e.g., replace "#" by "#".

Thank you all!
Harald